# Adding Azure AD's policies to Startup after Auth 2.0 migration

Tags: azure-active-directory, asp.net-core-2.0, azure-ad-graph-api

I recently asked a similar question, but it was with AAD B2C in regard. Now I'm wondering how to properly add policies to Azure Active Directory authentication in my app. Currently, my Startup class looks like this :

```
namespace Auth
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
                .AddEnvironmentVariables();

            Configuration = builder.Build();
        }

        private IConfigurationRoot Configuration { get; }


        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddMvc(opts =>
            {
                opts.Filters.Add(typeof(AdalTokenAcquisitionExceptionFilter));
            });

            services.AddAuthorization(o =>
            {

            });

            services.AddAuthentication(auth =>
            {
                auth.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                auth.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                auth.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            })           

            .AddCookie()
            .AddOpenIdConnect(opts =>
            {
                Configuration.GetSection("Authentication").Bind(opts);

                opts.Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents
                {
                    OnAuthorizationCodeReceived = async ctx =>
                    {
                        HttpRequest request = ctx.HttpContext.Request;
                        string currentUri = UriHelper.BuildAbsolute(request.Scheme, request.Host, request.PathBase, request.Path);
                        var credential = new ClientCredential(ctx.Options.ClientId, ctx.Options.ClientSecret);

                        IDistributedCache distributedCache = ctx.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<IDistributedCache>();

                        string userId = ctx.Principal.FindFirst("http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/objectidentifier").Value;

                        var cache = new AdalDistributedTokenCache(distributedCache, userId);

                        var authContext = new AuthenticationContext(ctx.Options.Authority, cache);

                        AuthenticationResult result = await authContext.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCodeAsync(
                        ctx.ProtocolMessage.Code, new Uri(currentUri), credential, ctx.Options.Resource);

                        ctx.HandleCodeRedemption(result.AccessToken, result.IdToken);
                    }
                };
            });
        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseAuthentication();

            app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();
        }


    }
}
```

I manage to acquire all needed tokens (for Azure Graph) succesfully later on, but right now the app uses some kind of default microsoft policy and I'm forced to use Microsoft authentication, while I'd also want to authenticate local tenant users. I have a sign up policy in my tenant called B2C_1_SignInPolicy, but I can't figure out how to pass it to my app's authentication. App is using a MVC-like model and .Net Core 2.0.

My best guess was adding a line similar to opts.AddPolicyUrl("https://...policyName); but I can't find a way to do that.

Comment: Can you clarify what you're trying to achieve? Specifically, when you say local tenant users do you mean you want to sign in users from a specifc Azure AD tenant or a local account store?

Comment: Local accounts from an Azure AD tenant - ones created via Create a user (local account) scheme from [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ad/graph/api/users-operations)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding the `AddOpenIdConnect` directly, you can refer the code below for the Asp.net Core 2.0 to interact with Azure AD B2C:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();

    services.AddAuthentication(sharedOptions =>
    {
        sharedOptions.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        sharedOptions.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    })
    .AddAzureAdB2C(options => Configuration.Bind("Authentication:AzureAdB2C", options))
    .AddCookie();

    // Add framework services.
    services.AddMvc();

    // Adds a default in-memory implementation of IDistributedCache.
    services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();
    services.AddSession(options =>
    {
        options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromHours(1);
        options.CookieHttpOnly = true;
    });


}

public static class AzureAdB2CAuthenticationBuilderExtensions
{
    public static AuthenticationBuilder AddAzureAdB2C(this AuthenticationBuilder builder)
        => builder.AddAzureAdB2C(_ =>
        {
        });

    public static AuthenticationBuilder AddAzureAdB2C(this AuthenticationBuilder builder, Action<AzureAdB2COptions> configureOptions)
    {
        builder.Services.Configure(configureOptions);
        builder.Services.AddSingleton<IConfigureOptions<OpenIdConnectOptions>, OpenIdConnectOptionsSetup>();
        builder.AddOpenIdConnect();
        return builder;
    }

    public class OpenIdConnectOptionsSetup : IConfigureNamedOptions<OpenIdConnectOptions>
    {

        public OpenIdConnectOptionsSetup(IOptions<AzureAdB2COptions> b2cOptions)
        {
            AzureAdB2COptions = b2cOptions.Value;
        }

        public AzureAdB2COptions AzureAdB2COptions { get; set; }

        public void Configure(string name, OpenIdConnectOptions options)
        {
            options.ClientId = AzureAdB2COptions.ClientId;
            options.Authority = AzureAdB2COptions.Authority;
            options.UseTokenLifetime = true;
            options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters() { NameClaimType = "name" };

            options.Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents()
            {
                OnRedirectToIdentityProvider = OnRedirectToIdentityProvider,
                OnRemoteFailure = OnRemoteFailure,
                OnAuthorizationCodeReceived = OnAuthorizationCodeReceived
            };
        }

        public void Configure(OpenIdConnectOptions options)
        {
            Configure(Options.DefaultName, options);
        }

        public Task OnRedirectToIdentityProvider(RedirectContext context)
        {
            var defaultPolicy = AzureAdB2COptions.DefaultPolicy;
            if (context.Properties.Items.TryGetValue(AzureAdB2COptions.PolicyAuthenticationProperty, out var policy) &&
                !policy.Equals(defaultPolicy))
            {
                context.ProtocolMessage.Scope = OpenIdConnectScope.OpenIdProfile;
                context.ProtocolMessage.ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.IdToken;
                context.ProtocolMessage.IssuerAddress = context.ProtocolMessage.IssuerAddress.ToLower().Replace(defaultPolicy.ToLower(), policy.ToLower());
                context.Properties.Items.Remove(AzureAdB2COptions.PolicyAuthenticationProperty);
            }
            else if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(AzureAdB2COptions.ApiUrl))
            {
                context.ProtocolMessage.Scope += $" offline_access {AzureAdB2COptions.ApiScopes}";
                context.ProtocolMessage.ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.CodeIdToken;
            }
            return Task.FromResult(0);
        }

        public Task OnRemoteFailure(RemoteFailureContext context)
        {
            context.HandleResponse();
            // Handle the error code that Azure AD B2C throws when trying to reset a password from the login page 
            // because password reset is not supported by a "sign-up or sign-in policy"
            if (context.Failure is OpenIdConnectProtocolException && context.Failure.Message.Contains("AADB2C90118"))
            {
                // If the user clicked the reset password link, redirect to the reset password route
                context.Response.Redirect("/Session/ResetPassword");
            }
            else if (context.Failure is OpenIdConnectProtocolException && context.Failure.Message.Contains("access_denied"))
            {
                context.Response.Redirect("/");
            }
            else
            {
                context.Response.Redirect("/Home/Error?message=" + context.Failure.Message);
            }
            return Task.FromResult(0);
        }

        public async Task OnAuthorizationCodeReceived(AuthorizationCodeReceivedContext context)
        {
            // Use MSAL to swap the code for an access token
            // Extract the code from the response notification
            var code = context.ProtocolMessage.Code;

            string signedInUserID = context.Principal.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;
            TokenCache userTokenCache = new MSALSessionCache(signedInUserID, context.HttpContext).GetMsalCacheInstance();
            ConfidentialClientApplication cca = new ConfidentialClientApplication(AzureAdB2COptions.ClientId, AzureAdB2COptions.Authority, AzureAdB2COptions.RedirectUri, new ClientCredential(AzureAdB2COptions.ClientSecret), userTokenCache, null);
            try
            {
                AuthenticationResult result = await cca.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCodeAsync(code, AzureAdB2COptions.ApiScopes.Split(' '));


                context.HandleCodeRedemption(result.AccessToken, result.IdToken);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //TODO: Handle
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And for the full code sample, you can refer the [core2.0 branch of active-directory-b2c-dotnetcore-webapp](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-dotnetcore-webapp/tree/core2.0/WebApp-OpenIDConnect-DotNet).

Comment: This doesn't work with Auth 2.0. And the token I get by using this doesn't let me connect to Azure Graph anyways.

Comment: This code sample is demonstrate to interact Azure AD B2C via Asp.net core 2.0 via OpenId connect protocol. As we discussed in the previews thread, to call the Azure AD Graph for Azure AD B2C, you need to interact with Client Credentials flow. At present, the Azure AD B2C app doesn't support to acquire the access token to delegate the user(refer [Azure AD B2C: Use the Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-devquickstarts-graph-dotnet)).